# Program will not open new windows

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to make a game for adroid and am having some problems with my windows.

I can open the "newgame" window from the "mainactivity", I'm trying to work on the "back" button, but I can't get it to work.

I also can't open new windows from the second "newgame" window (was testing if it would start to "load")

This may be a stupid mistake but I have no idea why its not working. Most app tutorials deal with one window and thus don't help me

My code:

**mainactivity.java:**

```
package dream.o.eternaty;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button NewGame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        NewGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.newgame);
            }
        });

        final Button Load = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.loadgame);
            }});  
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**newgame.java:**

```
package dream.o.eternaty;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class NewGame extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newgame);
        final Button Back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newgameback);
        Back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.loadgame);
            }
        });
    };

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }});
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail on "can't get it to work"? What is it exactly that doesn't work, and what have you tried?

Answer (score 9):

You shouldn't be transitioning the views, but actually starting a new activity for NewGame, as that's what you've declared it as, you can do it like this

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NewGame.class);
startActivityForResult(newIntent, 0);
```

in your MainActivity's onClick listener